Disable 'keydown' event listener for some keys
I want my Bootstrap tab switchers to stop eating Up and Down keys, so the page could scroll instead, as if they are not focused.
$('input[type="radio"][role="tab"]').on('keydown keyup', function (e)
{
    if (e.key == 'ArrowDown' || e.key == 'ArrowUp')
    {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        // So far so good.

        $('body')[0].dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent(e.type, { 'key': e.key }));

        // No effect :(
    }
});

The code above made the controls stop responding to Up and Down, but unfortunately the page doesn't scroll nevertheless.
UPD Here's MRE: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/forms/checks-radios/#radio-toggle-buttons. Click any of the buttons (“Checked” or “Radio”) and try pressing ←, ↑, ↓ and →. I'm fine with ← and →, but I want the page to scroll, when I press ↓ and ↑.
UPD2 This kind of works:
$('input[type="radio"][role="tab"]').on('keydown keyup', function (e)
{
    if (e.key == 'ArrowDown' || e.key == 'ArrowUp')
    {
        e.stopImmediatePropagation();
        e.preventDefault();

        document.activeElement.blur();
    }
});

After the first pressing on ↓ or ↑, the element loses focus, then the page starts scrolling as usual. Not exactly what I wanted, but it's even better from UX viewpoint, I guess.

What's the default bootstrap behavior of pressing up/down with a radio button focussed, that you are trying to prevent?  Any chance you can upgrade your question to incliude a MRE?

e.preventDefault(); prevents the default action (scroll up/down)

I suspect the issue is that you're sending keyup/down to body and it's not body that handles the default scrolling of the page.  And possibly the event is incomplete (possibly).

Hello @James, please see the answer, I've it updated to include the MRE link.

Hello @fdomn-m. Sure it does prevent. Otherwise BS would switch the inputs. But I create a new event and hope it should make the page scroll.

I don't think re-dispatching the keyboard event will work.  It might work for entering text into a field but probably not for scrolling a document.
I suggest you stick with preventDefault, and take control of the scroll yourself.  You might need to change that part of the code to suit your page, but here's my example.


$('input[type="radio"][role="tab"]').on('keydown keyup', function (e)
{
    if (e.key == 'ArrowDown' || e.key == 'ArrowUp')
    {

        e.preventDefault();
        if (e.type === 'keydown') {
          window.scrollBy({
            left: 0, 
            top: e.key === 'ArrowDown' ? 30 : -30,
            behavior: "smooth"
          });
        }
    }
});
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<p>prior content</p>

<input type="radio" role="tab" class="btn-check" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked>
<label class="btn btn-secondary" for="option1">Checked</label>

<input type="radio" role="tab" class="btn-check" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off">
<label class="btn btn-secondary" for="option2">Radio</label>

<input type="radio" role="tab" class="btn-check" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off" disabled>
<label class="btn btn-secondary" for="option3">Disabled</label>

<input type="radio" role="tab" class="btn-check" name="options" id="option4" autocomplete="off">
<label class="btn btn-secondary" for="option4">Radio</label>


<p>following content</p>
<p>following content</p>
<p>following content</p>
<p>following content</p>
<p>following content</p>
<p>following content</p>
<p>following content</p>
<p>following content</p>
<p>following content</p>
<p>following content</p>
<p>following content</p>
<p>following content</p>




Thank you. I've already thought about scrolling myself, but the problem is if you use scrollBy, you need to calculate somehow, how many pixels is one line. scrollByLines does the thing, but it's FF-only. document.activeElement.blur(); seems the best so far to me.
